# Why do I need to add -lstdc++ to my Other Linker Flags?

Tags: c++, objective-c, linker

An [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701393/link-error-about-opencv-in-xcode) made me realize that I need to add -lstdc++ to my "Other Linker Flags" to get my project to compile.

If I compile my code directly into my project, it runs fine. If I build it into a framework and include that framework, it complains:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from: ...
```

Adding -lstdc++ seems to solve the problem. It's great that it works, but can someone help me understand why I only see this issue when treating my code as framework?

Comment: Because OpenCV is written in C++.

Comment: @H2CO3 ... **and** you are selecting a specific C++ library

Comment: Note that while the linked question refers to OpenCV, I am not using OpenCV.

Comment: I'd guess you're running into a gcc vs. g++ situation. If you use `g++`, it'll link with libstdc++ by default. If you use `gcc`, the compiler will detect c++ based on file extension, but you need to specify libstdc++ explicitly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ah, so when I compile my source the fact that I'm including a .mm file is tipping off the compiler / linker?

Comment: Actually I can confirm that it is. Nice.

Comment: I can also set "Compile Code As" to Objective-C++ and have it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jerry Coffin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961127/why-do-i-need-to-add-lstdc-to-my-other-linker-flags#comment19258289_13961127) was the helpful answer. The compiler was detecting the .mm extension and switching to Obj-C++ for the framework build, but had no indication that the build including the framework should also be compiled this way.